# ArithmeticError causing "Rank(A) < p or Rank([G; A]) < n" error in cvxpy

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I'm trying to use cvxpy (and hence cvxopt) to model optimal power flow in a relatively simple network with 28 nodes and 37 lines, but getting a "Rank(A) < p or Rank([G; A]) < n" error.

(Using the same code, I can find the optimal solution for a much simpler network with 4 nodes and 4 lines.)

I've checked very carefully that the constraints are not inconsistent (using my answer to this question on Stack Overflow: 
[Check constraints are ok in cvxpy with actual values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974122/check-constraints-are-ok-in-cvxpy-with-actual-values) )

Here is the traceback:

```
File "main.py", line 201, in test_simple_optimisation
    p, bids, offers = optimize_flow(bids, offers, lines, nodes, injections_from_schedule, shift_factors, admittance.T)
  File "main.py", line 143, in optimize_flow
    p.solve()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/cvxpy/programs.py", line 169, in solve
obj,valid = solve_prog(new_p,quiet)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/cvxpy/procedures/solve_prog.py", line 44, in solve_prog
    sol = call_solver(p_expanded,quiet)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/cvxpy/procedures/call_solver.py", line 78, in call_solver
    r =  solvers.conelp(c,G,h,dims,A,b)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py", line 687, in conelp
    raise ValueError("Rank(A) < p or Rank([G; A]) < n")
ValueError: Rank(A) < p or Rank([G; A]) < n
```

When I look at /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py", line 687, it is actually rescuing an arithmetic error

```
 685         try: f = kktsolver(W)
 686         except ArithmeticError:..
 687             raise ValueError("Rank(A) < p or Rank([G; A]) < n")
```

Does that make sense? Why would an arithmetic error i.e. something like an `OverflowError`, `ZeroDivisionError`, `FloatingPointError`, unless cvxpy has extended ArithmeticError mean that the problem is ill described i.e. has Rank(A) < p or Rank([G; A]) < n"?

Answer (score 7):

Well, it turns out that removing some redundant constraints did solve the problem (as suggested on the cvxopt google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cvxopt/qlu3CK1TdVQ . I'm not sure why the `ArithmeticError` was being thrown.

Actually, the constraints I removed were not just dependent on other constraints, but guaranteed to be satisfied for any input, because of how I constructed the problem.